# How to adjust constraints with collapsing SearchBar in large iOS11 NavigationBar

Tags: swift

How do I adjust the constraint when pushing a new `UIViewController` when a `UISearchController` is implemented as `self.navigationItem.searchController = search`

[image]

New controller pushed: SearchBar collapses but leaves View with `constrait to top = 0` on the initial position.

(The background of the ViewController is yellow for easy understanding of the matter)

[image]

Implementation:

```
viewDidLoad() {

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    search.searchResultsUpdater = self
    search.definesPresentationContext = true
    search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    search.searchBar.tintColor = UI.COLOR_WHITE
    search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    self.navigationItem.searchController = search
}
```

I have tried using `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` without success and the `tableView` implements `self.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always`

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up your constraints in Storyboard? Could you show them too?

Comment: constraints are not the issue. just a tableview inside a viewcontroller with `0 top, 0 bottom, 0 leading, 0 trailing`

Comment: Ok, and these values are all set to the SafeArea of the ViewController?

Comment: Yes they are created in IB with SafeArea.